# Можно ли загрузить приложение в App store для одного телефона?

Tags: swift, xcode

сейчас пишу приложение для iPhone 11 Pro Max в среде Xcode на языке swift(обычное приложение single view App) и я хотел спросить можно ли как то обозначить что бы это приложение шло только на iPhone 11? Чтобы его не возможно было скачать на версии которые были до iPhone 11? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста как и где это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности нет. 
Максимум можно в настройках проекта в Deployment Info оставить только iPhone и указать последнюю версию iOS, что уменьшит количество устройств, на которых будет доступно ваше приложение, но указать только iPhone 11 Pro Max нельзя.
[image: Deployment Info]